# How to assemble a springform pan?

Tags: pan

The bottom sheet of a springform pan typically has bumps and a raised lip. Should the lip go up or down?

I've probably done it both ways in the past. Is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: At first I was quite surprised, because my own pans happen to have a different kind of lip, and it is quite clear that the pan is supposed to fit in only one way. Adding a clear picture of your type of pan, with the lip visible, would improve the question.

Comment: @rumtscho I considered adding a picture but I was pressed for time. Maybe I'll add it later.

Answer (score 3):

It's personal preference.

However, it's easier to cover the base of the pan in grease-proof paper when the lip is downward.  When the lip is upwards, it can be difficult to get the lining paper into the edges at the bottom without it crinkling a lot.

You get slightly less mix into the pan, but it's not really noticeable.  For me, it's easier to handle a downward lip.

Answer (score 3):

The lip is supposed to be down, but the sky won't fall if you get it upside down. If you put the lip up you get a lip shaped indentation in the finished cake, and you have to clean underneath it, which can be a pain.